# How to make custom audio player applicable to multiple audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have multiple HTML audio on my page, and want to apply this custom audio player to them. The thing is, this only works for the first audio, and not for the second, third and fourth. Is there any way where I can solve this problem?

My JavaScript code:

```
        const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        const playPauseButton = document.querySelector('.play-button');
        const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
        const progress = document.querySelector('.progress-controls');
        const playButton = document.querySelector('.playing');
        const pauseButton = document.querySelector('.paused');
        
        const playPause = () => {
            if(audio.paused){
                audio.play()
                playButton.style.display = 'none';
                pauseButton.style.display = '';
            }
            else{
                audio.pause()
                playButton.style.display = '';
                pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function pause(){
            pauseButton.style.display = 'none'
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', pause);
        
        playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', playPause);
        
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
            var progress = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
            progressBar.style.width = progress * 100 + "%";
        });
        
        document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            if (event.code === 'Space') {
                playPause(); 
            }
            if (event.code === 'KeyP') {
                playPause(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should post[mre],  **including** HTML too that you are referring too.